# where do I tell strongswan to find the ipsec.conf file?

Tags: centos, strongswan

https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/IpsecStarter

Im on centos. Centos renames the ipsec command "strongswan".

i put ipsec.conf in /etc/strongswan but it doesnt read it when I run `strongswan start`.

I edited /etc/strongswan/strongswan.d/starter.conf to point to the ipsec.conf but that didnt work either

Comment: On Ubuntu it's in the /etc (ie.: /etc/ipsec.conf) and Strongswan (executable named "ipsec") loads it from there.

Comment: i want to know how strongswan finds it. what strongswan config points to it